# trying to deserialize JSON unsuccesfully

Tags: json, arduino, deserialization, i2c

I am trying to deserialize an array of chars using the ArduinoJson Lib. The chars are coming from a I2C connection using Wire library. They come successfully so I don't think there is an issue there.

When trying to de-serialize at run time I get the message "deserializeJson() failed: EmptyInput".

From ArduinoJson Troubleshooter's report

```
The issue happens at run time
The issue concerns deserialization
deserializeJson() returns EmptyInput
Input comes neither from an HTTP response, nor a file, nor a stream
```

The part of code that deserialization fails is here:

```
void callback(char payload[], unsigned int msg_size) {
      Serial.print("Message arrived ");
      for (int i=0;i<msg_size;i++) {
      Serial.print((payload[i]));
      }
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload, msg_size);
      
      if (error) {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        return;
      }
      
      const char* command = doc["cmd"];
      Serial.print("command ");
      Serial.println(command);
    
      //rest of code
    }
    
    
    
void setup() {
      
      //communications
      Wire.begin(0x8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
      Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
      Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
      Serial.print("Start_");
      Serial.println(ver);

    }
     
     
void loop() {
        
    // function that executes whenever data is received from master
    // this function is registered as an event, see setup()
    void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
      char buff[60];
      
      Serial.print("how many=");
      Serial.println(howMany);
      //initialize buffers
      buff[0] = '\0';
      int i = 0;
      while (0 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
        //char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
        char c = Wire.read();
        Serial.print(c);          // print the character
        buff[i] = c;
        buff[i+1] = '\0';         // Add a NULL after each character
        i++;
      }
      
      int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("x:");
      Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
      Serial.print("BUFFER:");
      for (int j=0; j < howMany; j++) {
        Serial.print(buff[j]);
      }
      Serial.println();  
      Serial.print("size:");  
      Serial.println(sizeof(buff));
      callback(buff, howMany);
    }
```

The print out from serial ide is here:

```
Start_v.0.1
how many=25
{"cmd":"demo","seq":"1"}
x:-1
BUFFER:{"cmd":"demo","seq":"1"}
size:60
Message arrived {"cmd":"demo","seq":"1"} deserializeJson() failed: EmptyInput
```

But the payload variable, as you see here is not empty.

Can you provide any debugging hints? Thank you

Edit: I have added more code that shows the i2c communication

```
from smbus import SMBus

addr = 0x8 # bus address
bus = SMBus(1) # indicates /dev/ic2-1
numb = 1

def StringToBytes(val):
    retVal = []
    for c in val:
        retVal.append(ord(c))
    return retVal

def writeData(arrayValue, i2c_address):
    byteValue = StringToBytes(arrayValue)
    # examples ---> 

    bus.write_i2c_block_data(i2c_address,0x00,byteValue)
    return -1

# main
print ("Enter command:")
while 1:

    cmd = input(">>>>   ")
    
    writeData(str(cmd), addr)
```

Comment: Please share your code on where you get the payload from? it is rare that I2C communication will return a JSON object.

Comment: @hcheung i did add the i2c part, thank you

Comment: `{"cmd":"demo","seq":"1"}` has 24 characters not 25.

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete and badly formatted, it doesn't really help for anyone to help you to identify the problem. From what you posted so far, I realised that you didn't allocate memory for `doc` with `StaticJsonDocument<32> doc;` prior using it!

Comment: @gre_gor
You are right and as i was advised i looked for nulls. After filtering the de serialization succeeded. I will insert the code above in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I filtered the incoming i2c buffer for nulls and the de serialization of JSON worked. I am not sure why the nulls are sent by rpi/python.

```
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  char buff[60];
  
  Serial.print("how many=");
  Serial.println(howMany);
  //initialize buffers
  buff[0] = '\0';
  int i = 0;
  while (0 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    if (c == '\0') {
      //ignore 
    } else {
      //char c = Wire.read();
      Serial.print(c);          // print the character
      buff[i] = c;
      buff[i+1] = '\0';         // Add a NULL after each character
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("x:");
  Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
  Serial.print("BUFFER:");
  for (int j=0; j < howMany; j++) {
    Serial.print(buff[j]);
  }
  Serial.println();  
  Serial.print("size:");  
  Serial.println(sizeof(buff));
  callback(buff, howMany);
  
}
```